# automating New-ADuser Script

Tags: powershell

I'm try to automate the new user process and having a little problem. I have an csv file that is exported from our system that holds all the students info. with this info I'm trying to map group *(this isn't AD group, its info from the other system)* they are in to OU in Active Directory.

if you look at the be code, for it $OUPath works if its, but this dumps all the users into a single OU.

```
$OUPath = 'OU=group1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'.
```

I've try If statement:

```
$OUPath = if ("$($User.OU)" -eq "group1") {"OU=group 1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"}
elseif ("$($User.OU)" -eq "group2") {"OU=group 2,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"}
else {"OU=LostAndFound,DC=domain,DC=com"}
```

I've also tried hashtable as you can below

```
$ImportPath = "C:\Temp\NewUsers.csv"
$ExportPath = "C:\Temp\Passwords.csv"
$DataBase = Import-Csv $ImportPath 
ForEach ( $User in $DataBase){
Try{
$OUPath = @{
"group 1" = 'OU=group1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'
"group 2" = 'OU=group2,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'
}
$DriveMap = "\\file03.domain.com\users$\$($User.Username)"
$Relam = "domain.com"
function Get-RandomPassword {
Param(
    [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
    [int]$Length
)
Begin {
    if ($Length -lt 4) {
        End
    }
    $Numbers = 1..9
    $LettersLower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.ToCharArray()
    $LettersUpper = 'ABCEDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.ToCharArray()
    $Special = '!@#$%^&*()=+[{}]/?<>'.ToCharArray()

    # For the 4 character types (upper, lower, numerical, and special)
    $N_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
    $L_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .4)
    $U_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
    $S_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
}
Process {
    $Pswrd = $LettersLower | Get-Random -Count $L_Count
    $Pswrd += $Numbers | Get-Random -Count $N_Count
    $Pswrd += $LettersUpper | Get-Random -Count $U_Count
    $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count $S_Count

    # If the password length isn't long enough (due to rounding), add X special characters
    # Where X is the difference between the desired length and the current length.
    if ($Pswrd.length -lt $Length) {
        $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count ($Length - $Pswrd.length)
    }

    # Lastly, grab the $Pswrd string and randomize the order
    $Pswrd = ($Pswrd | Get-Random -Count $Length) -join ""
}
End {
    $Pswrd
}
}
$password = Get-RandomPassword -Length 9
$username = $User.Username
$ou = $User.OU
if (Get-ADUser -F { SamAccountName -eq $username }) {
Write-Warning "A user account with username $($User.Username) already exists in Active 
Directory."
}
else {
New-ADUser `
-Name "$($User.Username)" `
-GivenName "$($User.Firstname)" `
-Surname "$($User.Lastname)" `
-initials "$($User.initials)" `
-sAMAccountName "$($User.Username)" `
-UserPrincipalName "$($User.Username)@$($Relam)" `
-AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $password -AsPlainText -Force) `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $False `
-OfficePhone "$($User.Telephone)" `
-title "$($User.Title)" `
-City "$($User.Office)" `
-Office "$($User.Office)" `
-Description "$($User.Title)" `
-Department "$($User.Department)" `
-DisplayName "$($User.Firstname) $($User.Lastname)" `
-homeDrive "H:" `
-homeDirectory "$($DriveMap)"`
-Enabled $True `
-EmailAddress "$($User.Username)@$($Relam)" `
-path $OUPath[$ou]
Write-Host "The user account $($User.Username) is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$User | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Initial Password" -Value $password - 
Force
}
# Export
$DataBase | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
}
Catch{
Write-Warning "Problem with creating account: $($User.Username) | $([datetime]::Now)"

}
}
```

---

**Edit**

```
FirstName,Initials,Lastname,Username,Department,Telephone,Title,Office,OU
Paul,A,Apptest,PApptest,Department of Test,555-555-5555,"Man of the World, PhD ",Center of the Earth,group 1
Paul,Z,Apptest2,PApptest2,Department of Production,+1 (555) 555-5555,Hermit,Cave,group 2
Paul,F,Apptest3,PApptest3,Department of Fail,5555555555,Nomad,Anywhere,
```

Image from notepad:

[image]

Updated, I had to start over and tried cutting back some of the code, so I could rap my head around it. PowerShell is still new to me. The Below code worked not sure way but it did.

```
function Get-RandomPassword {
Param(
    [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
    [int]$Length
)
Begin {
    $Length = [math]::Max($length, 4)
    $Numbers = 1..9
    $LettersLower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.ToCharArray()
    $LettersUpper = 'ABCEDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.ToCharArray()
    $Special = '!@#$%^&*()=+[{}]/?<>'.ToCharArray()

    # For the 4 character types (upper, lower, numerical, and special)
    $N_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
    $L_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .4)
    $U_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
    $S_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
}
Process {
    $Pswrd = $LettersLower | Get-Random -Count $L_Count
    $Pswrd += $Numbers | Get-Random -Count $N_Count
    $Pswrd += $LettersUpper | Get-Random -Count $U_Count
    $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count $S_Count

    # If the password length isn't long enough (due to rounding), add X special characters
    # Where X is the difference between the desired length and the current length.
    if ($Pswrd.length -lt $Length) {
        $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count ($Length - $Pswrd.length)
    }

    # Lastly, grab the $Pswrd string and randomize the order
    $Pswrd = ($Pswrd | Get-Random -Count $Length) -join ""
}
End {
    $Pswrd
}
}

$ImportPath = "C:\Temp\StartOver\TestUsers.csv"
$ExportPath = "C:\Temp\StartOver\Passwords.csv"
$DataBase   = Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath 
$OUPath     = @{
'Group 1' = 'OU=Group1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=adelphi,DC=internal'
'Group 2' = 'OU=Group2,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=adelphi,DC=internal'
}

ForEach ($User in $DataBase)
{
 Try{

    $Account  = $User.UserN
    $password = Get-RandomPassword -Length 9
    $ThePath  = $OUPath[$User.OU]
    $Relam = "domain.com"

    If(Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Account}){
        Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
    }
    Else {
    $UserProps = @{
        Name                  = $Account
        GivenName             = $User.FirstN
        Surname               = $User.LastN
        Initials              = $User.Init
        SamAccountName        = $Account
        UserPrincipalName     = "$Account@$Relam"
        AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        OfficePhone           = $User.Phone
        Title                 = $User.Title
        City                  = $User.Office
        Office                = $User.Office
        Description           = $User.Title
        Department            = $User.Depart
        DisplayName           = "$($User.FirstN) $($User.LastN)"
        HomeDrive             = 'H:'
        HomeDirectory         = "\\file03.domain.com\users$\$Account"
        Enabled               = $true
        EmailAddress          = "$Account@$Relam"
        Path                  = $ThePath
    }
        $newUser = New-ADUser @userProps -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "The user account $Account) is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $User | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Initial Password" -Value $password -Force
        }
    # Export
    $DataBase | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
    }
Catch{
    Write-Warning "Problem with creating account: $Account`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
     }
        }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the DistinguishedNames of the OU's are correct? At one point you use `OU=group 1` (note the space) and also `OU=group1` (no space).. Do these OU's exist already? I would also strongly recommend you have a look at [About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) so you can stop using those nasty backticks on all the parameters.

Comment: Yes the OU are correct and already setup. Groups with space is the lookup that is being matched with the csv. The csv is export of another system so it so it’s not the same. I’ll take a look at splatting

Comment: Good to hear, except.. you now export your database again and again (overwriting it each time) in every iteration.. That doesn't seem very useful to me..

Comment: you are right, ill have to update that. I did another question for you. the below doesn't work. what I'm trying to do is the same as I did with -path. the real domain has over 100+ OU and each one has its own set of groups. after is created i wanted to add them to the groups base off the OU they are going in

$GroupLookup @{
"Group 1" = {
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "WiFi" -Members "$($User.UserN)"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "VPN" -Members "$($User.UserN)"
}
"Group 2"= {
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "WiFi" -Members "$($User.UserN)"
}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for explaining.

The helper function `Get-RandomPassword` should be on top of the script, not inside the foreach loop. (I didn't rewrite that, but it *can* return passwords with all lowercase or all uppercase letters..)

Next, I think the code could do with a few more tests to see if you have a mapping for the group --> ou path and if so, if a OU with that DistinguishedName actually exists in your environment.

As commented, [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) makes the code easier to read and in this case, you can reuse that same Hashtable for the CSV output:

Try

```
function Get-RandomPassword {
    Param(
        [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$Length
    )
    Begin {
        $Length = [math]::Max($length, 4)
        $Numbers = 1..9
        $LettersLower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.ToCharArray()
        $LettersUpper = 'ABCEDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.ToCharArray()
        $Special = '!@#$%^&*()=+[{}]/?<>'.ToCharArray()

        # For the 4 character types (upper, lower, numerical, and special)
        $N_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
        $L_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .4)
        $U_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
        $S_Count = [math]::Round($Length * .2)
    }
    Process {
        $Pswrd = $LettersLower | Get-Random -Count $L_Count
        $Pswrd += $Numbers | Get-Random -Count $N_Count
        $Pswrd += $LettersUpper | Get-Random -Count $U_Count
        $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count $S_Count

        # If the password length isn't long enough (due to rounding), add X special characters
        # Where X is the difference between the desired length and the current length.
        if ($Pswrd.length -lt $Length) {
            $Pswrd += $Special | Get-Random -Count ($Length - $Pswrd.length)
        }

        # Lastly, grab the $Pswrd string and randomize the order
        $Pswrd = ($Pswrd | Get-Random -Count $Length) -join ""
    }
    End {
        $Pswrd
    }
}

$ImportPath = "C:\Temp\NewUsers.csv"
$ExportPath = "C:\Temp\Passwords.csv"
$DataBase   = Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath
# these are just examples. In ADUC, go to the properties of the OU and copy the value from DistinguishedName
$OUPath = @{
    "group 1" = 'OU=group1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'
    "group 2" = 'OU=group2,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'
}

$result = foreach ($User in $DataBase) {
    $username = $User.Username
    Try{
        # test if the user already exists
        if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" ) {
            Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
            continue  # skip this user and proceed with the next one
        }
        # test if we have a valid mapping for the OU
        $ouDN = $null     # initialize to $null
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($($User.OU))) {
            Write-Warning "No OU path available for user $username"
        }
        else {
            $ou = $User.OU
            if (!$OUPath.ContainsKey($ou)) {
                Write-Warning "Could not map OU '$ou' to any of the defined Organizational Units."
            }
            else {
                # test if the environment indeed has a OU with that DistinguishedName
                try {
                    $ouObject = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $ou -ErrorAction Stop
                    $ouDN = $ouObject.DistinguishedName
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Warning "OU '$ou' does not exist in the domain."
                }
            }
        }
        $Relam    = 'domain.com"'
        $password = Get-RandomPassword -Length 9

        # create a Splatting Hashtable. 
        # here, I'm using an [ordered] hash because we will also use it to output to CSV
        # so if you change the order here, this will also be the order of the columns in the CSV
        $userProps = [ordered]@{
            Name                  = $username
            GivenName             = $User.Firstname
            Surname               = $User.Lastname
            Initials              = $User.initials
            SamAccountName        = $username
            UserPrincipalName     = "$username@$Relam"
            AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            OfficePhone           = $User.Telephone
            Title                 = $User.Title
            City                  = $User.Office
            Office                = $User.Office
            Description           = $User.Title
            Department            = $User.Department
            DisplayName           = "$($User.Firstname) $($User.Lastname)"
            HomeDrive             = 'H:'
            HomeDirectory         = "\\file03.domain.com\users$\$username"
            Enabled               = $true
            EmailAddress          = "$username@$Relam"
        }
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ouDN)) {
            # only add the Path parameter if we succeeded in finding the target OU
            $userProps['Path']   = $ouDN
        }

        # create the new user. 
        # -ErrorAction Stop will also have the code catch non-terminating exceptions
        $newUser = New-ADUser @userProps -ErrorAction Stop
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ouDN)) {
            Write-Host "The user account $username is created in the DEFAULT USERS OU" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "The user account $username is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        }
        # to output to CSV, rewrite the AccountPassword item in the hash to its human readable password
        $userProps.AccountPassword = $password
        # next output the hash converted to PsObject to be collected in variable $result
        [PsCustomObject]$userProps
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Warning "Problem with creating account: $username`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Export to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>If you want more details of an exception, then look at `$_.Exception.Message` inside the catch block</sup>

Comment: I move function Get-RandomPassword and ran it again and it still failed. so then I added $_.Exception.Message in and I got the error below.(this error is using the setup above.

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: I all ran it using the below and got this error:(The object name has bad syntax)

$OUPath = if ("$($User.OU)" -eq "group1") {"OU=group 1,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"}
elseif ("$($User.OU)" -eq "group2") {"OU=group 2,OU=Administration,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"}
else {"OU=LostAndFound,DC=domain,DC=com"}

Comment: Hey Theo thanks for your help on this, I've updated the info and also added a image of it(I think I did it the right way). I check the csv and it looks right in notepad, but even after manually recreating the csv I still get the the error about  -path not valid.

Comment: Also there is three test users, the third is missing a group because I'm going to have the script put anyone missing info in the OU field to be created in LostandFound, I still want it to create the users and then later check with HR on where they need to be.

Comment: @Paul Please see my revised answer. I have added more strict tests for the OU path. Also, if there is anything wrong with that path (or missing in the csv), the user will now still be created, but will appear in the default Users OU which is usually at `CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com`. Because that path can be redirected, you need to move them to the LostAndFound container afterwards (or some more appropriate container in your environment)

Comment: I see the changes you made but its still the same error, its like its not even checking the $OUPath.
WARNING: Problem with creating account: PApptest
Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.

Also i change Get-ADUser to: (Get-ADUser { SamAccountName -eq $($username) })
it was throwing an error with what you have there, but not sure if I did it right.

Comment: @Paul Then please check the OU paths in the Hashtable and do a `Write-Host "path = $($userProps['Path'])" just before the New-ADUser line

Comment: Hey Theo, I had to start over to get my head around it, using what you sent last I rebuilt it. I update my original question and added it to the bottom. this worked, not sure why lol